# Powershell get spare licenses

Tags: powershell, ms-office, azure-powershell, ms-office-script

**I am trying to get the amount of spare licenses available from the `Get-MsolAccountSku` command.**

Here's the code (output below)

```
$Licenses = Get-MsolAccountSku
$spare = Foreach ($License in $licenses)
{
  ($License.ActiveUnits - $License.ConsumedUnits)   
}

Get-MsolAccountSku | Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits,@{L=’SpareLicenses’;E={$spare}}
```

**I want to add a column to the right of the output to list the amount of licenses available from the subtraction in the `ForEach` loop.**

```
ActiveUnits ConsumedUnits
----------- -------------
         30            26
       1601             1
         30            29
         25             0
          5             3
          1             0
      12550         12465
    1000000         12461
      12550         12466
      12555         12468
         31            19
      12550         12464
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$spare` object is not needed, just update the Select to do the calculation...

```
Get-MsolAccountSku | 
Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits,
@{L=’SpareLicenses’;E={$_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits}}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [about Calculated Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2):

> The calculated property is defined by a hashtable containing key-value pairs that specify the name of the new property, an expression to calculate the value, and optional formatting information.

> - [`expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2#hashtable-key-definitions) - A **script block** used to calculate the value of the new property.

Following your code, you should change the `foreach` loop for a script block:

```
$Licenses = Get-MsolAccountSku
$spare = { $_.ActiveUnits - $_.ConsumedUnits }

# $_ - References to each object being passed through the pipeline
# See about Automatic Variables for more information

Get-MsolAccountSku |
Select-Object -Property AccountSkuId,ActiveUnits,ConsumedUnits,@{
    Name = 'SpareLicenses'
    Expression = $spare
}
```